Ты придешь или нет? О соединительном значении разделительного союза ИЛИ
Рассмотрим два предложения:
(1)Ты придешь или нЕт?  Запятой нет, предложения в составе ССП соединяет вопросительная интонация.
(2) Ты придЕшь(,) или уж не ждАть? Нужна запятая или нет? Семантика похожая, но могут появиться сомнения. Иди все же нет никаких сомнений и решение однозначное, но какое? Ведь разделительное значение ИЛИ  явно ощущается по тексту.
При решении задачи можно вспомнить о двойственности (или даже тройственности) союза ИЛИ: сколько возможных ситуаций он может обозначать? Информация на эту тему есть в Русской корпусной грамматике 5.1.1. Союз ИЛИ
Вопрос имеет отношение к теме: Учись(?) или пропадёшь.
